# How to pass down input value during onSubmit in React?

Tags: forms, reactjs

I have a basic form in React that asks for username. After entering desired username (say `iggy`), I want it to console.log that username, `iggy`.

Here is the thing: traditionally, I would do something like

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={username: ''}
  ...

  handleUsernameEnter: function(e){
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    })
  },
  ...
  <form onSubmit={this.handleUsernameSubmission}>
    <input placeholder="enter username" ref="usernameItem" onChange={this.handleUsernameEnter} />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit username" />
  </form>
  ...
```

I would store username in `state` as user inputs it. No problem. This time, I don't want to save username in state yet. I want user to enter username on the input text, when user clicks submit button, `handleUsernameSubmission` would somehow get the `value` of the username that the user enters, and console.log that value. I couldn't figure out how to pass the value from `input` to `username` variable in `handleUsernameSubmission`.

```
handleUsernameSubmission: function(username){
    console.log('username entered: ', username)
  },
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iggyfiddle/adj4Ln1p/3/

How can I get the username to be passed down from form's input value to `username` variable in `handleUserSubmission` without saving it to state first?

My gut feeling says I need to use `ref` in the input, but I am not sure how to reference the onsubmit to get the `value` from that particular input. Something like `<form onSubmit={this.handleUsernameSubmission(input.'usernameItem')}>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use `this.refs` here of course.

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Here is the code:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

  handleUsernameSubmission: function(e){
    if(e) e.preventDefault();
    const name = this.refs.usernameItem.value;
    console.log('Your name is', name);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleUsernameSubmission}>
          <input placeholder="enter username" ref="usernameItem" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit username" />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Also, I've implemented ES6 version of it, it looks better:

```
class Form extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    if(e) e.preventDefault();
    const name = this.input.value;
    console.log('Your name is', name);
  }

  render(){
     return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" ref={(element) => { this.input = element }} />
        <button>Submit!</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

> React supports a special attribute that you can attach to any
>   component. The ref attribute takes a callback function, and the
>   callback will be executed immediately after the component is mounted
>   or unmounted.
>
> When the ref attribute is used on an HTML element, the ref callback
>   receives the underlying DOM element as its argument.
>   React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the
>   component mounts, and call it with null when it unmounts.
>
> Using the ref callback just to set a property on the class is a common
>   pattern for accessing DOM elements. The preferred way is to set the
>   property in the ref callback like in the above example.

Comment: Quick question, on `ref={(element) => {this.input = element}}...`, how would you describe `this.input`?

Comment: @Iggy, I've updated my answer and added explanation from the docs.

Comment: Excellent. I read the document a few hours ago and got a headache. Now after playing around with the code, re-read and re-re-read the explanation, my migraine went down substantially. Clarity! Thanks for the help, man.

Answer (score 5):

You also can use `event` object.

So your submit will look like that in this case.

```
class Form extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    if(e) e.preventDefault();
    const [input] = e.target.children
    console.log('Your name is', input.value);
  }

  render(){
     return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input placeholder="Your name" type="text"/>
        <button>Submit!</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So you basically get DOMElement of `form` using `e.target` then you also access its `children` DOMElements and using array spread ES6 feature, you take the first one, which is your `input` then you use its `value`, in your `console.log` call.

Without ES6 spread it will look like.

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    if(e) e.preventDefault();
    const input = e.target.children[0]
    console.log('Your name is', input.value);
  }
```

Of course, it's usually better to use `refs` but when you really have that simple example, you can do it this way. But in a real app, I wouldn't rely on elements order etc.

Comment: This works very well for a functional component as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use ref, yes. I'm going to assume you're using JQuery, just because it simplifies my answer here, but you don't **need** JQuery (see the other answer for a non-JQuery solution). There are two ways of using refs.

```
<form onSubmit={ this.onSubmit }>
    <input ref="username" /> <-- #1

    <input ref={ (input) => { this.input = $(input); } } <-- #2
</form>

onSubmit = (event) => {
    // using method #1
    let username = $(this.refs.username).val();

    // using method #2
    let username = this.input.val();
};
```

if you want a `handleUsernameSubmit` with a signature that accepts the username as a param, I would combine it with the above and do something like

```
<form onSubmit={ () => { this.handleUsernameSubmit(this.input.val()) }) }>
```

for the `form#onSubmit`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use traditional way: `document.getElementById`

```
<form method="post" path="/home" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
<TextField id="username" label="Username" variant="outlined"/>

handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(document.getElementById('username').value);
}
```